# Fork github repository and its pull requests

Tags: git, github, fork, pull-request

I'm looking for a way to recover pull requests from a forked repository. Is it possible?

Comment: You may want to consider changing the account to an Organization, if you're trying to move ownership of a repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When one fork a repository, GitHub only forks the code, not the pull requests.

However, you can retrieve the pull requests from the upstream repository by leveraging the **[GitHub Pull Request API](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/)**.

- **syntax** GET /repos/:user/:repo/pulls
- **sample:** https://api.github.com/repos/libgit2/libgit2/pulls

By default, only the PR which are currently **opened** are listed. You can access the **closed** ones by passing an optional *state* parameter.

- **sample:** https://api.github.com/repos/libgit2/libgit2/pulls?state=closed

*Note:* This will allow you to retrieve the metatdata of the pull requests of any repository (forked or not).

**Alternative (by hand) way**

```
$ mkdir libgit2
$ git clone http://github.com/libgit2/libgit2
$ git fetch origin +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/pull/*
```

This will retrieve every pull request (*opened* and *closed*) from the GitHub hosted repository and create a branch per pull request in you local repository.

**Warning:** this is an undocumented GitHub feature and might stop working without notice.

Comment: The "alternative" gives me the remote's refs, but no branches for them. Could this be info no longer valid or am I missing something how to turn those refs into branches?

Comment: Edit: Using this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638235/git-checkout-remote-reference) I could get it to work, great advice!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a way to do this via the UI, but the API does offer pull request access [here](http://develop.github.com/p/pulls.html) so you could do it programatically fairly simply.

Comment: This is the old version of the API