# git checkout remote reference

Tags: git, github

I have a list of pull requests on github. I can fetch the pull requests like this:

```
git fetch origin +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

I get output like this:

```
* [new ref]         refs/pull/1/head -> origin/pr/1/head
* [new ref]         refs/pull/1/merge -> origin/pr/1/merge
* [new ref]         refs/pull/10/head -> origin/pr/10/head
* [new ref]         refs/pull/10/merge -> origin/pr/10/merge
* [new ref]         refs/pull/11/head -> origin/pr/11/head
* [new ref]         refs/pull/11/merge -> origin/pr/11/merge
```

Now I want to checkout one of those refs. Nothing I try seems to work:

```
$ git checkout refs/pull/1/head
error: pathspec 'refs/pull/1/head' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Or:

```
git checkout origin/pr/1/head
error: pathspec 'origin/pr/1/head' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

How can I checkout this reference?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The first command (`git checkout refs/pull/1/head`) didn't work because `refs/pull/1/head` is the name of the reference in the remote repository.  You don't have a reference with that name in your local repository because your `fetch` refspec translated it to `refs/remotes/origin/pr/1/head`.

The second command (`git checkout origin/pr/1/head`) should have worked, although it should have given you a "detached HEAD" warning.  Was there a typo that you fixed when posting your question to Stack Overflow?

Your `fetch` refspec told git to translate the remote references into local references in the `refs/remotes` directory.  The references in that directory are treated specially -- they're "remote references" meant to indicate the state of the remote repository the last time you did a `fetch`.  Normally you don't want to check those refs out directly -- you want to create a local branch that is configured to "follow" or "track" the remote reference (which enables special convenience shortcuts such as the `@{u}` revision parameter and easier `push`/`pull` usage).

Try:

```
git fetch origin +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
git checkout -b whatever-branch-name-you-want origin/pr/1/head
```

The above creates a new local branch called `whatever-branch-name-you-want` (I recommend calling it `pr/1/head`) pointing at the same commit as `origin/pr/1/head`, configures `whatever-branch-name-you-want` to track `origin/pr/1/head`, then switches to the new branch.

Comment: You are correct. The second command worked. Not sure what I was doing the first time. Thanks.

Comment: Is it also possible to push to the newly created branch and modify the pull request?

Answer (score 0):

Check out what's available to checkout with

```
git branch -a
```

Comment: Very useful flag indeed.